# Hide column when the statement is TRUE

Tags: php, html

How can I hide this row if the variable `$status` is equal to `'Delivered'`?

```
<?php if ($status == 'Delivered') { ?>
<tr>
    <td class="normalfont" >Reason for failed delivery:</td>
    <td><input type="text"
        STYLE="color: #0000; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #E1E5E6;"
        size="50" class="frmSearch" name="courier_del_reason"
        readonly="readonly"
        value="<?=$objResult["courier_del_reason"];?>" /></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

I've used some codes but still it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I am hoping that by column, you mean table row (given that is what the code you have given does) in which case it is a simple change of the condition:

```
<?php if ($status != 'Delivered') { ?>
              //  ^ This bit was changed.
<tr>
    <td class="normalfont" STYLE="font-family: Verdana;">Reason for failed delivery:</td>
    <td><input type="text"
        STYLE="color: #0000; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #E1E5E6;"
        size="50" class="frmSearch" name="courier_del_reason"
        readonly="readonly"
        value="<?=$objResult["courier_del_reason"];?>" /></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

The code will now only execute this bit of the value of `$status` is not `'Delivered'`.

Comment: Sir, when the $status is equal to 'Delivered' the textbox will retrieved 'Delivered', else $equal to 'Failed' the textbox retrived NULL even if have value. I want to hide this row if the value of $status is 'Delivered'